# How can I check if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is enabled for my domain?

Tags: cross-domain, cors

If I have configured `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain` correctly, should it be listed in the response headers if I view them using the [web developer plugin](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)? I don't see it. Should it be there?

I have tried viewing the response headers after submitting my post request, and just calling the page.

---

**Background**

I need to transfer a couple of values from *mydomain* to *receivingdomain* via XMLHttpRequest POST request and am trying to troubleshoot

> XMLHttpRequest Page1.asp cannot load https://receivingdomain. No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

If I turn on the [Allow-Control-Allow-Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) plug-in my post requests work correctly. However, when this plug-in is disabled, my post requests are being received ok (the data is inserted into the database) - I'm just not getting any result back from the receiving server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool that allows you to set the origin header in your test request (e.g. Postman or if using VSCode , try REST client extension)

then send a GET request to your endpoint while setting the origin header manually in your request e.g.

```
GET <your endpoint>
origin: http://mydomain
```

the above request should return 200 if the allow origin includes the domain name.
then try with another domain name that is not in the list e.g.

```
GET <your endpoint>
origin: http://anotherdomain
```

this should return 403 Forbidden with some message that CORS origin is not in allowed list or something to that effect depending on your server side code)